# putting inline style using ternary operator php

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am trying to add css inline style based on a php variable's value.
I tried doing so with ternary operator, and also I converted the variable value to float. But the css is not being applied as expected.

```
       <tbody>
        <?php
        $totalLeaveTaken = 0.00;
        $totalBalance = 0.00;
            foreach ($GetEmployeeLeaveBalance as $member):
                $totalLeaveTaken += $member['usedDays'];
                $totalBalance += $member['Remaining_Leave_Days'];
                $leaveBalance = floatval($member['Remaining_Leave_Days']);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $member['title']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['maxDays']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['usedDays']; ?></td>
                <!-- <td><?php echo gettype($leaveBalance);?></td> -->
                <td
                <?php 
                ($leaveBalance < 0) ? 
                "style='background-color:red;'" : "style='background-color:green;'"
                ?>
                >
                <?php echo $member['Remaining_Leave_Days']; ?>    
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="background-color: #33CCFF; font-weight: bold;">Total: <?php echo number_format($totalLeaveTaken, 2); ?></td>
            <td style="background-color: #33CCFF; font-weight: bold;">Total: <?php echo 
            number_format($totalBalance, 2); ?></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

But the simple inline styling is working fine.

Comment: "echo" seems to be missing?

Comment: @OfirBaruch.. putting echo displays an error.. I have used such styling in other projects.. and they are working fine (without echo).. don't know why it is not working this time..

Comment: <td
                <?= 
                ($leaveBalance < 0) ? 
                "style='background-color:red;'" : "style='background-color:green;'"
                ?>
                >

Comment: Isn't true as the condition returns the statement and doesn't automatically prints it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the echo command prior to the condition.
Basically if the condition returns true or false, the statements are being returned and not necessary being echoed.

```
<?php
echo ($leaveBalance < 0) ? "style='background-color:red;'" : "style='background-color:green;'"
?>
```

Sidenote, A better practice:

Since both of the returned strings are style, there's no point in repeating it (developers are lazy :] ). So you can simply write:

```
<td style='background-color: <?php echo ($leaveBalance < 0) ? "red" : "green" ?>'>
```

Comment: thanks... earlier I used <?= ?> and that's why it was working.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not

```
<?php 
    ($leaveBalance < 0) ? "style='background-color:red;'" : "style='background-color:green;'"
?>
```

but

```
<?php 
    echo (($leaveBalance < 0) ? "style='background-color:red;'" : "style='background-color:green;'");
?>
```

or

```
<?= (($leaveBalance < 0) ? "style='background-color:red;'" : "style='background-color:green;'"); ?>
```

Comment: AHHH.. yes.. I tried the latter one with my previous one.. and that comes with 'echo' ... thanks a lot.. :)