# Implement inline ternary operator in embedded HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, conditional-operator

I am a learner in PHP, and I have a code in which I am implementing HTML5 code. What I am trying to do is to embed the inline ternary operator in my placeholder.

I have followed this link, but none of them are having same problem statement:

1. [Putting inline style using ternary operator php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326510/putting-inline-style-using-ternary-operator-php)
2. [Inline PHP/HTML Ternary If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405986/inline-php-html-ternary-if)

**My Code:**

```
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='".$value."' placeholder='HERE I WANT TO OPERATE'>";
```

**Tried:** I have tried this in my code, but I am getting errors

```
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='".$value."' placeholder='"empty($value) ? 'Some Text' : 'Enter Data';"'>";
```

I know how to do the ternary operation outside the `echo code` in PHP, but I am looking for this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operation will return a string. As such, it has to be concatenated to the rest of the string.

```
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='".$value."' placeholder='". (empty($value) ? 'Some Text' : 'Enter Data') ."'>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Separate part of string with condition with help of `()`:

```
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' 
value='".$value."' 
placeholder='".(empty($value) ? "Some Text" : "Enter Data")."'>";
```

*Note: you're using `empty()` function on `$value`, if it has some text then it will go into `false` case -> "Enter Data". Use `!empty()` instead.*:

```
(!empty($value) ? "Some Text" : "Enter Data")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this... hope it will help

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"$value\" placeholder=" . $value == "" ? "Some Text" : "Enter Data";">";
```